# Why am I getting an "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." when trying to cast a Type to interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I have a public class Typewriter with an interface IDialogueAnimation. In a method in the class DialoguePrinter I get all objects with the interface IDialogueAnimation. They come as Types and I want to cast them to IDialogueAnimation. However, it won't let me and I'm getting an "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." error. Why is this? Thanks!

I've checked that Typewriter and IDialogueAnimation are in the same assembly (which is something that has come up when I've tried to search for a solution).

```
IDialogueAnimation GetAnimationInterfaceFormName(string name)
{
    Type parentType = typeof(IDialogueAnimation);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
    IEnumerable<Type> imp = types.Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(parentType));

    foreach (var item in imp)
    {
        if (item.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
        {
            return (IDialogueAnimation) item;
        }
    }

    Debug.LogError("Can't find any animation with name " + name);
    return null;
}
```

This is the Interface

```
public interface IDialogueAnimation
{

    bool IsPlaying { get; set; }

    IEnumerator Run(OrderedDictionary wordGroup, float speed);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `item` variable is of type [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type). You can't cast a `Type` to your interface because the class `Type` doesn't implement your interface.

You can only cast an *instance* of a type that implements your interface to the interface, not the `Type` itself.

If you want to return a new instance of that type, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_) to do that:

```
if (item.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower()) {
    return (IDialogueAnimation) Activator.CreateInstance(item);
}
```

If the type's constructor requires parameters, then you need to [pass the parameters for the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) as well. Something like:

```
return (IDialogueAnimation) Activator.CreateInstance(item, something, something);
```